# What happens when Detect Magic is used upon something that is magically invisible?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, magic, invisibility

Does a simple casting of Detect Magic reveal the presence of magical invisibility?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**Yes**. And the quotation to back this up comes from the [PRD glossary on invisibility](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/glossary.html#_invisibility) where it says almost at the bottom:

> Invisibility does not thwart divination spells.

If we look up [Detect Magic](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/spells/detectMagic.html#_detect-magic) it says plainly that it is of the divination school. Thus it can be used to detect the aura from magical invisibility.

Indirectly confirming this is the fact that the new [Mythic Adventures invisibility spell](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/mythicAdventures/mythicSpells/invisibility.html#_invisibility-mythic) specifically says:

> The invisible target can't be detected with detect magic or other
>   spells that detect magic auras. The invisibility can't be penetrated,
>   revealed, or dispelled by spells of 2nd level or lower (such as see
>   invisibility or glitterdust), though true seeing and dust of
>   appearance can reveal the invisible target's presence.

It's therefore pretty clear that per the RAW, Detect Magic will indeed reveal the presence of (non-mythic) magical invisibility.

Comment: Since this answer's at the top, I just want to note @Zachiel's comment in the other answer that the creature's square is pinpointed, but the creature still has total concealment relative to the *detect magic* beneficiary.

Answer (score 15):

### Yes.

Invisibility does not conceal any aura, it just fouls sight.
You also need a way to hide auras if you want your character/item to be undetectable.

Comment: Worth noting that an invisible creature still has Total Concealment under *detect magic*.

Comment: Wonderful.  Is there a source/reference/link to a definitive answer or perhaps something in the book I missed that makes this clear?

Comment: I'm working by logic, by just looking at the spell's description on the SRD. Invisibility never talks about concealing any aura. Invisibility is a spell, so it has an aura. Detect Magic lets you see auras, which are not made invisible.

Answer (score 11):

Presence, yes. But the most basic use of the spell only says that something is there, not where it is, so it wouldn't spoil the *invisibility* effect.

To actually get an idea of where the invisible person is, you'd have to concentrate for a couple of rounds. Two rounds is enough if the *invisibility* spell is the strongest in the area, but that's easy to camouflage by putting a stronger aura somewhere else. You'd have to concentrate for three rounds to be guaranteed to nail down an invisible person's location.

Comment: Not so good in the heat of combat but maybe good for finding an object like a gem or treasure chest that has been 'cloaked'.