# Detect magic (drows) and invisibility (spells)

Tags: pathfinder-1e

I'm wondering about detect magic from the drow nobles. It is a constant effect. From the description you see that an aura is around the area. This question [What happens when Detect Magic is used upon something that is magically invisible?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/30332/what-happens-when-detect-magic-is-used-upon-something-that-is-magically-invisible) already says that you can see invisible targets (but not exactly where) with a normal detect magic spell.

So my question is: would you be able to see enough (high drow noble...thus detect magic is constant) to make attacks against the invisible target?

Comment: This appears to be answered by the answers on the question you link to. How is this question different?

Comment: That is where I'm not so sure of. They are talking about detect magic there which takes concentration (lvl 0 spell). As I mentioned it is stated there they get the idea something is there but not enough to target it. But what I'm talking here is a CONSTANT spell taht is on sight and gives an aura thus I'm not sure if THAT is enough to give you enough details to attack invisible creatures or not

Comment: I believe how it works is that drow nobles have it constantly on, but to use it they must still concentrate. But, that question isn't mentioned anywhere above. If that's what you really meant to ask, you should ask that directly instead of asking about attacking an invisible target.

Comment: it is constantly on and I'm not sure if that changes how invisibility spells are affected by that variant of detect magic