# How does arcane sight interact with invisible creatures?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells

What would [Arcane Sight](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/a/arcane-sight) tell you about something under [invisibility](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/i/invisibility)?

It was [confirmed/answered here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/30370/23058) that detect magic will tell you the presence of aura of invisibility (and if their willing to sit still the location). So arcane sight should tell you the same information as soon as you see it within 120 feet.

As far as I can determine, all you will be able to find out is the location of the aura (and presumably the size of what its concealing, say a small, medium, or large creature) but not if its a statue or creature thats under invisibility (unless its carrying gear or under the effect of spells).

Assuming that there is an invisible creature within your sight, what exactly could you determine about it? According to the spell you should be able to determine the auras of all of the active spells on the creature, as well as the magic items it is carrying.

Are you able to spend the standard action to focus on where the invisible creature is and tell if it is a spell caster and all the other possible information you can gleam?

Comment: How different in practical terms is this question from [this question](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/30332/8610)?

Comment: This was more asking for the dept of information that could be gleamed while using arcane sight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The effect is similar to that of a **detect magic spell**, but Arcane Sight does not require concentration and discerns aura location and power more quickly.

[Arcane Sight](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/a/arcane-sight) says it works as [Detect Magic](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/d/detect-magic), then lists the exceptions, of which none say it shouldn't work on invisible creatures.

Things you can tell if there is an invisible creature that's within your 60' cone:

- There is something with a magical aura within your sight;
- The exact location of this aura;
- Any other magic aura on this invisible creature.

And assuming you pass a **Knowledge(Arcana)** check:

- School of this aura as *Ilusion*;

> Are you able to spend the standard action to focus on where the invisible creature is and tell if it is a spell caster and all the other possible information you can glean?

If you do spend a **Standard Action** to analyze this creature, you do obtain information about its spellcasting abilities, or if the creature can use spell-like abilities.

> If you concentrate on a specific creature within 120 feet of you as a standard action, you can **determine** whether it has any **spellcasting or spell-like abilities**, whether these are **arcane or divine** (spell-like abilities register as arcane), and the strength of the most powerful spell or spell-like ability the creature currently has available for use.

However, it says: *If you concentrate on a specific creature within 120 feet of you*. If the creature is invisible, **all you see is her aura, not the creature** herself.

For that you would need [True Seeing](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/t/true-seeing), or [Goggles of True Sight](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/e-g/goggles-truesight):

> The subject sees through normal and magical darkness, notices secret doors hidden by magic, sees the exact locations of creatures or objects under blur or displacement effects, **sees invisible creatures** or objects normally, sees through illusions, and sees the true form of polymorphed, changed, or transmuted things.

It's worth mentioning that True Seeing is a 6th level spell, while Arcane Sight is a 3rd level spell, and Detect Magic is merely a 0th level spell (cantrip/orison/knack).

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my understanding, you can discern that there is something, the approximate size, location and whether or not it is moving, as well as any additional magical auras from either the creature/object or any items it might have, should they have auras in the first place. You could also use this in conjunction with Knowledge checks to find out the school of magic of any of the said auras, but you would not be able to identify the creature or its abilities as you're not actually seeing the creature, you're only seeing the aura surrounding it. In fact, you cannot even be sure if there is something or someone hidden, or if there is a spell aura for some other reason.